# ComponentFactoryResolver "Can't resolve all parameter for..." - but providers are present

Tags: angular

I'm facing a strange issue with `angular@4.1.3`. In our large app, we had to make some components customizable, i.e. allowing user to dynamically add and remove them from the homepage. These components are declared in NgModules imported by the root one, and work properly today (without dynamic loading).

I then began using the `ngComponentOutlet` directive, but I found those component could not be dynamically built, due to:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for XXXComponent: ([object Object], ?, [object Object], ?, [object Object], ?)
```

What's really strange is missing parameters are Services provided in the App root module, and, even stranger, I can actually resolve them via `Injector` in the `HomePageComponent`:

```
// This works!
const foo = this.injector.get(ProfileService);
```

The same happens with ComponentFactoryResolver:

```
// This yield the same error as above...
const widgetComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(XXXComponent);
```

My guess this is related to child injectors, but I don't understand why the root one seems not to be taken into account...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put up some reproduction? It means that angular doesn't know type passed to constructor

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have the same situation